# How to add a JSP page into Spring boot web application

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I generate a sprint boot by https://start.spring.io/. Then I added a JSP view to the project. But it is not rendering. I don't know what could be wrong. Here is my project code:-

Main App:-

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

    }
```

Configuration:-

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Bean
        public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }

        @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
                DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }
    }
```

Controller:-

```
    @Controller
    public class HelloController3 {
        @RequestMapping("/hello")
        public String hello(Model model, @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
            model.addAttribute("name", name);
            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

I have my hello.jsp file located at /WEB-INF/ directory. What am I missing? It doesn't show any error messsage as well.

Comment: can you provide your pom.xml as wel ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot what is returned to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/) example. Try putting prefix and suffix in the application.properties file as mentioned there.
File:**/src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

You will not need `MvcConfiguration` here. Please let me know if this helped you, if not then share your results, I will try to analyze the issue further.

Comment: I downloaded the project and try to compile and run. But throws error. So I am suspicious about it.

Comment: If I put application.properties at /src/main/resources/. Is that enough? I don't see anywhere it is reading the value of spring.mvc.view.prefix and spring.mvc.view.suffix. How spring will know aout it?

Comment: I gave that reference to learn from it. Anyway, what error/exception you are facing in that project?
As you have said you downloaded the project from the spring-boot site, you will get that in the project by default.

Comment: Try one more thing, put your JSP file in **/WEB-INF/jsp** folder, see if it works.

Comment: go to **http://start.spring.io** and select the dependencies you wish to include in your project like web, REST, thymeleaf, JPA, HATEOS, etc and download the project. You will find the application.properties in the downloaded project **src\main\resources**.

Answer (score 0):

first you extends SpringBootServletInitilizer in your Application and put your jsp page inside views like ..WEB-INF/ Views/hello.jsp.

you create your application class like this ....

```
enter code here@SpringBootApplication
```

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

}

here i am giving you one link that is related to your post..

https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot-hello-world-example-with-jsp/

This is helpful for you..

add suffix and prefix:--

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /

spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

Comment: The example throws error:-  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.hellokoding.springboot.WebApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:182) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]